# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '||='

Tags: javascript, next.js, pdf.js, react-pdf-viewer

I need to build nextjs project with PDFViewer using @react-pdf-viewer, but when collecting page there are some error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '||='`.

The problem is occured from pdf.js in `node_modules`, I try to change `||=` to `||` in `pdf.js`, and build no error.

But I need to deploy in hosting and need to download pdf.js from `yarn install`, some code that I change before will be restored.

How can I solve it?

Comment: `||=` is a recent addition to the language, what Node version are you using?

Comment: im using 14.17.0

Comment: Update to >=15.0 in order to use `||=`

Comment: welcome to front-end, you may start with reading https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js#using-pdfjs-in-a-web-application chapter

Comment: @FZs it works, but i chose to downgrade `@react-pdf-viewer`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-pdf-next-js-y4ev2?file=/components/pdf-viewer.js:191-280) is great example how to correctly setup react-pdf with NextJS.

However, as mentioned in comments, you still get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '||='` with a node version below 15, so **you need to upgrade to >=15.0**.

Then it works as expected.